# How to insert 1 million record into multiple server's database

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am facing a big performance issue when want to sync from a host database to multiple server database.

Detail:
Host(microsoft sql server) has 7 tables (microsoft sql server) and total 1 million records. These records need to synced to 300 server's databases. It is not request for checking or compare. So I can just clear the table's data and insert whatever data from Host Server. But the performance speed is slow.

My Host's database has 30 tables and so in the other 300+ client's server database. But I only need to sync 7 tables from host's database to other databases.

Client's server is Host's linked server. Their are in different place and different server.

I found some samples but that is not really helpful. I have not decided which method yet. So I am open for any suitable method. Do you have any idea and sample for me? A thousand of thanks!

How frequent: maybe 1 week 1 time, but my client only off from 10pm until 8am.

My sample code is :

```
set @scriptTruncate  = N'
EXEC ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].sys.sp_executesql N''
--ALTER TABLE [Module_Function] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Module_Function_Module1]
Delete from [dbo].[USER_STORE];
Delete from [dbo].[USER_ROLE_DEPT];
Delete from  [dbo].[ROLE_FUNCTION];
Delete from [dbo].[ROLE_MODULE];
Delete from  [dbo].[POMADUSER];
Delete from  [dbo].[HHTUSER];
Delete from [dbo].[ROLE];
Delete from [dbo].[Store];
'';';
                    set @scriptTInsert1  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @Store'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[Store]([STORE_Code],[STORE_LongDesc],[STORE_ShortDesc],[CURR_CODE],[IS_STORE],[CNTRY_CODE],[ADDR_1],[ADDR_2],[ADDR_3],[CITY],[STATE],[ZIP],[ISD],[AREA],[Phone_number],[ISD_FAX],[AREA_FAX],[FAX_NUMBER],[MANAGER_NAME],[TYPE_CODE],[AR_NUM],[PRC_BOOK_NUMBER],[FNC_CODE],[GL_CO],[CREATE_DATE],[Modified_On],[Deleted_On],[StockTakeDate],[IPAddress],[Check_SalesHistory],[Print_DeletedSKU],[Print_InactiveSKU],[Product_ShelfCapacity],[Org_Lvl_Child],[Fin_Banner],[Fin_Accd],[TradeStoreCode],[NonTradeStoreCode])
SELECT [STORE_Code],[STORE_LongDesc],[STORE_ShortDesc],[CURR_CODE],[IS_STORE],[CNTRY_CODE],[ADDR_1],[ADDR_2],[ADDR_3],[CITY],[STATE],[ZIP],[ISD],[AREA],[Phone_number],[ISD_FAX],[AREA_FAX],[FAX_NUMBER],[MANAGER_NAME],[TYPE_CODE],[AR_NUM],[PRC_BOOK_NUMBER],[FNC_CODE],[GL_CO],[CREATE_DATE],[Modified_On],[Deleted_On],[StockTakeDate],[IPAddress],[Check_SalesHistory],[Print_DeletedSKU],[Print_InactiveSKU],[Product_ShelfCapacity],[Org_Lvl_Child],[Fin_Banner],[Fin_Accd],[TradeStoreCode],[NonTradeStoreCode] 
FROM [CAS].[dbo].[Store];'
set @scriptTInsert2  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @HHTUSER'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[HHTUSER]
    SELECT * FROM  [CAS].[dbo].[HHTUSER];'
set @scriptTInsert3  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @ROLE'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[ROLE]
    SELECT * FROM  [CAS].[dbo].[ROLE];'
set @scriptTInsert4  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @USER_STORE'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[USER_STORE]
    SELECT * FROM  [CAS].[dbo].[USER_STORE];'
set @scriptTInsert5  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @POMADUSER'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[POMADUSER]
    SELECT * FROM  [CAS].[dbo].[POMADUSER];'
set @scriptTInsert6  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @ROLE_MODULE'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[ROLE_MODULE]
    SELECT * FROM  [CAS].[dbo].[ROLE_MODULE];'
set @scriptTInsert7  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @ROLE_FUNCTION'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[ROLE_FUNCTION]
    SELECT * FROM  [CAS].[dbo].[ROLE_FUNCTION];'
set @scriptTInsert8  = N'
                    Select Getdate(),''Start @USER_ROLE_DEPT'';
INSERT INTO ['+@IPAddress+'].[POM].[dbo].[USER_ROLE_DEPT]
    SELECT * FROM  [CAS].[dbo].[USER_ROLE_DEPT];
--ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Module_Function]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Module_Function_Module1] FOREIGN KEY([Module_Code])
--REFERENCES [dbo].[Module] ([Module_Code])
';
            BEGIN TRY
            Select Getdate(),'Start @scriptTruncate'
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTruncate
            Select Getdate(),'Start @scriptTInsert'
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert1
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert2
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert3
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert4
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert5
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert6
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert7
                EXEC sp_executesql @scriptTInsert8
```

Comment: We have no idea how you're doing it now so it's difficult to suggest an improvement. Are you using mirroring? replication? SSIS? Backup/Restore?

Comment: Hi Nick, currently I only use Insert Into ... select statement. It cause me like 1 hour + per server. I have 30 table in 1 database and only the 7 table will need to sync to other server.

Comment: Is the select over a linked sever? Please edit your question and include the select/insert information you just posted, and whether you are using a linked server. Then I suggest you install sp_WhoIsActive and observe the waits to see if it is a network bandwidth issue or a table locking issue. Also edit the question to indicate how frequently you need this replication to occur; Weekly, daily, hourly, five minutes?

Comment: Hi Nick,ya. I just update it.

Comment: If you only need the data to be replicated once a week, a simple option might be to just send (or pull) a compressed backup out to the 300 sites, then run a script at each site to restore the backup then merge the 7 tables in. Does that seem like it could work for you? It depends how much unneeded data is in the other tables. If there is a lot of redundant data in the backup then you could instead export the tables in native format using BCP, zip those up and again copy the zipped file out. The first step would be compare size of zipped files vs compressed backup

Comment: You basically need to test various approaches and see how they work for you.

Comment: Thanks Nick, do you have any sample for this? thanks

Comment: Here's a guide to using BCP: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/ You should export your 7 tables using this (in native format) and zip them up. How big? Now create a compressed backup. How big is it? (zipped and unzipped). There are many approaches to replication and you should choose one that suits your ability to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick! I check this now.!

Comment: @456qwe123asd , be carefull with backup and restore... This option is one of most inefficient. Realize, that after restore all client "metadata" about indexes, index effectivity and statistics will be fired out... Maybe it is easy for you, but be aware that it will have negative impact on clients side. Try to use SSIS package with catalog and fire 1 package asynchronously multiple times with multiple parameters...

Comment: Thanks Matej, can you have any good sample ?